# state not define in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

hello guys i follow everything provide no google but none of these working i m new to vuex 3.0.1 and vue 2.5 below of my code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;


 var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
 Vue.use(VueResource);


   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     console.log(this.$store.state.authUser)// this is not working
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && 
        (!this.$store.state.authUser || 
  this.$store.state.authUser === 'null')){
  const authUser = localStorage.getItem('authUser')
   console.log('here log');
   next({ path: '/', })

 }else{
   console.log('bhar else redirect');
  next()  
 }

});
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
   template: '<App/>',

    components: {
     App
     }
 })
```

everything work porperly if i remove this this.$store.state.authUser it work here is my store.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
 import Vuex from 'vuex'
 import userStore from './user/userStore.js'
 Vue.use(Vuex)
  const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

 export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules:{
    userStore
  },

 strict:debug
 })
```

here is my userStore

```
 const state = {
   authUser:null
    }
const mutations  = {
    SET_AUTH_USER(state,userObj){
        state.authUser = userObj
        }
 }
   const actions = {
    setUserObject :({commit},userObj) =>{
        commit('SET_AUTH_USER',userObj)
     }
   }
  export default {
      state, mutations, actions
 }
```

here is my login succcess from where i trie to dispatch value in store note i have value in store

```
  this.$store.dispatch('setUserObject',response.data.id)
```

i does everything properly but don't know why it throw error Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing your store in the router's `beforeEach` guard using `this.$store`. But `this` is not your vue instance and has no `$store` property.

Since you are importing the store using `import store from './store'`, you can use that `store` import to access your store as follows:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     console.log(store.state.userStore.authUser)// this will log put authUser from userStore module
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && 
        (!store.state.userStore.authUser || 
  store.state.userStore.authUser === 'null')){
  const authUser = localStorage.getItem('authUser')
   console.log('here log');
   next({ path: '/', })

 }else{
   console.log('bhar else redirect');
  next()  
 }

});
```

The `authUser` property belongs to the `userStore` module, so to access it you use

```
store.state.userStore.authUser
```

Comment: thanks i have one more problem how i can set axios header inside  router.beforeeach